# Can you disable Fast Startup but keep Hibernation option?

Tags: boot, shutdown, hibernate, powercfg, win10-fast-startup

It is possible to keep Windows Fast Startup enabled for shutdowns but remove "Hibernate" as a shutdown option by running the elevated command `powercfg /h /type reduced`, but what about the opposite? I want to disable Fast Startup, so that a normal shutdown (e.g. `shutdown /s`) is truly a full shutdown, with no kernel hiberfil. However, I would like to keep the *option* to Hibernate the PC (e.g. `shutdown /h`), in which case obviously a hiberfil would be created for both the kernel and the user session.

Is this possible?

Comment: Your question doesn’t make sense. The hibernation file is used by Hibernation. What you want to disable is the [Hybrid Sleep](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/turn-off-hybrid-sleep-when-pc-is-on-battery-or-plugged-in?expand_article=1).

Comment: No, Hybrid Sleep is different. I am talking about [Fast Startup](https://www.howtogeek.com/856514/how-to-disable-fast-startup-on-windows-10/) (not Boot, sorry). See definition of Fast Startup: "When Fast Startup mode is enabled and you turn off your PC, Windows saves the system kernel, drivers, and current system state to a hibernation file. Unlike proper hibernation, your login sessions and apps aren’t saved."

Comment: So, to use the terminology from the linked page, I am asking whether it is possible to disable "Fast Startup mode" while still keeping the option to enter "proper hibernation" (because right now when you disable Fast Startup, it removes Hibernation from the Shutdown Options menu).